# $filter('date') not updating format when using $scope variable for format in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-filters

In angular I have a simple drop down to set a data format. 
For the sake of learning the angularJS data binding, I would like to intercept the selected value in the controller and use it there within a $filter('date') to change the displayed date, according to the selected format.
Below is the HTML and controller code:

```
<select ng-model="selector">
   <option value="dd/MM/yyyy">Euro</option>
   <option value="MM/dd/yyyy">USA</option>
   <option value="yyyy/MM/dd">JPN</option>
</select>
<span>
     Formatted Date: {{ formattedDate }}
</span>


$scope.selector = 'MM/dd/yyyy';
var nowDate = new Date();
$scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')(nowDate, $scope.selector);
```

By selecting a new value from the drop down, the selector variable is set correctly, but the formattedDate does not change, but it remains initialized to the first value.
By using the angular filter in HTML it works fine:

```
{{ nowDate | date : selector}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Watch way

Add `$watch` to fire filter on `selector` change:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return $scope.selector;
 },
  function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')(nowDate, newValue);
 });
```

Demo 1 in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2367/)</kbd>

---

### ng-chage way

Set `ng-chage` directive to `<select>`

```
$scope.fireFilter = function(){
    $scope.formattedDate = $filter('date')(nowDate, $scope.selector);
}
```

*HTML*

```
<select ng-model="selector" ng-change="fireFilter()">
```

Demo 2 in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2368/)</kbd>

---

For better performance I would use `ng-chage` way