# reapply filter when scope changes

Tags: angularjs

I have applied a custom filter to check checkboxes belonging to which group have been checked.

The filter basically hides the groups of checkboxes that none of them have been checked.

What I need to do is, reapply the filter when a box is checked or unchecked. .so that when all the checkboxes belonging to a group are unchecked, rest of the groups show up.How do I go about it?

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in filtered=(properties  | filter:filterByCategory| groupBy: 'name') ">

  <li>Group name: <strong>{{ key }}</strong></li>

          <div  ng-repeat="prop in value">
            <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[key][$index]" ng-change="Changed"/>
                        <span>{{prop.Property}}</span>
            </label>
          </div>
 </ul>
```

I guess I need something like this:
[mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177810/filterdate-not-updating-format-when-using-scope-variable-for-format-in-con) with `ng-change`.

Plunkr:

[Code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/EldBaL5pcGEjauLlNduh?p=preview)

Try:

I tried changing it to  this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[key][$index]" ng-change="fireFilter(key)">
```

and

```
$scope.fireFilter = function(prop){
    console.log("PROP WHEN CALLED" + prop);
    $filter('filterByCategory')(prop);
    $scope.filter=[];
}
});
```

but it gives me an error that says:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=filterByCategoryFilterProvider%20%3C-%20filterByCategoryFilter
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:6:450
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:36:145
    at Object.c [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:34:236)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:36:213
    at Object.c [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:34:236)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:124:238)
    at k.$scope.fireFilter (file:///C:/Users/dev4/Desktop/Grouping/js/scipt.js:40:2)
    at db.functionCall (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:176:387)
    at k.$get.k.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:15)
```

Comment: The error is because you're using this filter:filterByCategory , but you don't specify filterByCategory (as far as I can see)

Comment: you can't create a custom filter in controller to use with `$filter`. Create a proper filter using `angular.module('myApp').filter(....)`

Comment: @AnaF: Check the code on Plunkr please.

Comment: @charlietfl: yes I realized that but yet unable to figure out a way to do it.

Comment: would be a lot simpler binding ng-model to a property of each item instead of a different scope object which is confusingly named `filter`. You shouldn't need `ng-change` if your filtering is done properly

Comment: @chanorlietfl: Yes, I agree that it should have been done implicitly if filter was working the way it should but I am not able to see how changing model from filter to a property would help when key is already a part of it.

Comment: Is this what you are wanting to do?  http://plnkr.co/edit/fpjC7skFtChBkeZrHAbe?p=preview

Comment: Yes, but all of them should not have been checked by default.

Comment: they aren't all checked by default, only a few were for proof of concept

Comment: Yes, but since I want to hide other groups other than the one marked item belongs to, selection from multiple groups isn't an option.

Comment: not clear at all what you are looking for , not sure what last comment even means